# MyBatis caching strategy in distributed system

Tags: caching, mybatis

I'd like to know how myBatis cache (local and second level) to handle data in distributed system. I have 5 instances running against Oracle db, and I use MyBatis for data access. All 5 instances are same but running on different servers. The Mybatis are configured to use SESSION cache, which being said the cache is cleared when any insert/delete/update statement is executed.

When 1 instance runs , the local cache of that server is cleared. How does the other 4 instances know the cache needs to be flushed/renewed?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built-in cache, no they don't. Never enable secondary cache if you are using MyBatis in a distributed environment with default cache because they don't know what happens each other and won't clear the staled cache when change happens.

You need to set up an external cache service, such as Ehcache and Redis, to make MyBatis secondary cache usable.
Please refer to http://mybatis.org/ehcache-cache/ and http://mybatis.org/redis-cache/

Answer (score 0):

Giving a track:

I guess all instances are behind a load balancer and running against a single Oracle DB.
Instances nodes would better be in a cluster, otherwise, how could they communicate with each other. Then cache may be shared between cluster's nodes, for example as stated in [Jboss doc, working with Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/4/html/clustering-entity-30-cache.html).

The question is more about how to configure server (or application, in files such as *beans.xml*) to use MyBatis cache.

If the SessionFactory is declared *@ApplicationScoped*, it could be enough.